# Java Generics: compareTo and “capture#-of ?”

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree, comparable

I'm trying to write an implementation of a BinaryTree whose object can be of any type that implements `Comparable`.  However, I realize that won't completely work.  For example, A String and a Double wouldn't be able to be inserted into the same tree, even though they both implement `Comparable`.

So, I would like to know if it's possible to write the code such that the BinaryTree can be instantiated with any value whose type implements `Comparable`, but any ensuing elements added to the tree must all share the same supertype as the root's value.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class BinaryTree {

    private Node root;

    public BinaryTree() {

        this.root = null;
    }

    public Node lookup(Comparable<Object> value) {

        return lookup(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node lookup(Node node, Comparable<Object> value) {

        Node match = null;

        if (match != node) {

            if (value == node.value) {
                match = node;
            } else if (value.compareTo(node.value) < 0) {
                return lookup(node.left, value);
            } else {
                return lookup(node.right, value);
            }
        }

        return match;
    }

    public Node lookupNonRecursively(Comparable<Object> value) {

        return lookupNonRecursively(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node lookupNonRecursively(Node node, Comparable<Object> value) {

        Node match = null;

        if (match != node) {

            if (value == node.value) {
                match = node;
            } else {

                Node root = node;
                boolean found = false;

                while (!found && root != null) {

                    if (root.value.compareTo(value) < 0) {

                        if (root.left == null) {

                            root.left = match = new Node(value);
                            found = true;
                        } else {
                            root = root.left;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (root.right == null) {

                            root.right = match = new Node(value);
                            found = true;
                        } else {
                            root = root.right;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return match;
    }

    public Node insert(Comparable<Object> value) {

        return insert(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node insert(Node node, Comparable<Object> value) {

        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(value);
        } else {
            if (node.value.compareTo(value) <= 0) {
                insert(node.left, value);
            } else {
                insert(node.right, value);
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    public Node insertNonRecursively(Comparable<Object> value) {

        return insertNonRecursively(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node insertNonRecursively(Node node, Comparable<Object> value) {

        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(value);
        } else {

            Node root = node;
            boolean inserted = false;

            while (!inserted) {

                if (node.value.compareTo(root.value) < 0) {

                    if (root.left == null) {
                        root.left = node = new Node(value);
                        inserted = true;
                    } else {
                        root = root.left;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (root.right == null) {
                        root.right = node = new Node(value);
                        inserted = true;
                    } else {
                        root = root.right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    public static class Node {

        private Node left;
        private Node right;
        private Comparable<Object> value;

        public Node(Comparable<Object> value) {

            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And as a test, this will throw the error, `The method insert(Comparable<Object>) in the type BinaryTree is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)`, if I try to run code like the following:

```
BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
tree.insert(new Integer(1));
```

You can see I've implemented some different `BinaryTree` methods for this class, but the same rules would need to apply: any value passed into `lookup()` or `insert()` would also need to share the root's supertype.  I have a feeling this is where some variant of `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is going to come into play, but my mind is just not figuring this one out.

Any ideas for how I might accomplish this?

As noted by @jp-jee, here's my solution (also with logic and other bugs fixed from untested first attempt), which works beautifully:

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private Node<T> root;

    public BinaryTree() {

        this.root = null;
    }

    public Node<T> lookup(T value) {

        return lookup(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node<T> lookup(Node<T> node, T value) {

        Node<T> match = null;

        if (match != node) {

            if (value.equals(node.value)) {
                match = node;
            } else if (value.compareTo(node.value) < 0) {
                return lookup(node.left, value);
            } else {
                return lookup(node.right, value);
            }
        }

        return match;
    }

    public Node<T> lookupNonRecursively(T value) {

        return lookupNonRecursively(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node<T> lookupNonRecursively(Node<T> node, T value) {

        Node<T> match = null;

        if (match != node && value != null) {

            if (value.equals(node.value)) {
                match = node;
            } else {

                Node<T> searchRoot = node;
                boolean found = false;

                while (!found && searchRoot != null) {

                    if (value.equals(searchRoot.value)) {
                        match = searchRoot;
                        found = true;
                    } else if (value.compareTo(searchRoot.value) < 0) {
                        searchRoot = searchRoot.left;
                    } else {
                        searchRoot = searchRoot.right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return match;
    }

    public void insert(T value) {

        this.root = insert(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node<T> insert(Node<T> node, T value) {

        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node<T>(value);
        } else {
            if (value.compareTo(node.value) <= 0) {
                node.left = insert(node.left, value);
            } else {
                node.right = insert(node.right, value);
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    public void insertNonRecursively(T value) {

        this.root = insertNonRecursively(this.root, value);
    }

    private Node<T> insertNonRecursively(Node<T> node, T value) {

        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node<T>(value);
        } else {

            Node<T> runner = node;
            boolean inserted = false;

            while (!inserted) {

                if (value.compareTo(runner.value) < 0) {

                    if (runner.left == null) {
                        runner.left = new Node<T>(value);
                        inserted = true;
                    } else {
                        runner = runner.left;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (runner.right == null) {
                        runner.right = new Node<T>(value);
                        inserted = true;
                    } else {
                        runner = runner.right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    public static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

        private Node<T> left;
        private Node<T> right;
        private T value;

        public Node(T value) {

            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node<T> getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public Node<T> getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you just try `<T extends Comparable<T>>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your Binary Tree generic like

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>>{
   ...
}
```

Whenever creating a `BinaryTree` instance, specify the containied type:

```
new BinaryTree<MyClass>();
```

Where `MyClass` must implement `Comparable<MyClass>`, i.e. be comparable to Objects of the same class.

Your methods would read as (example):

```
 public Node lookup(T value) { ... }
```

The same applies for your `Node` class. Make it generic the same way.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @newacct, is that because then any type whose supertype is T can also use the tree?

Comment: @liltitus27: Yes. I'm not sure what you meant by that, but for example, if `class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>`, and `class Dog extends Animal`, then `Dog` would be comparable to another `Dog` (as well as other animals), but `Dog` would not satisfy the original bounds, because `Dog` is not a subtype of `Comparable<Dog>`. `Comparable` is purely a "consumer" with respect to `T`, and therefore by the PECS rule, it should always be used with `super`-bounded wildcards.